# JavaScript substring: how to pull out specific information from a string

Tags: javascript, substring

I have a div with a "style" attribute for a background image.
It pulls back the following:

```
background-image: url("<img alt="" src="/mysite/imagegallery/PublishingImages/Gallery/image.png" style="BORDER&#58;0px solid;" />"); background-attachment: scroll; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-color: transparent;
```

I would like to strip out the following

```
/mysite/imagegallery/Images/Gallery/image.png
```

Once I have this, I can write the JS to replace the style attribute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe what you're ultimately trying to do? Your code examples don't make much sense to me.

Comment: This looks like invalid CSS: `url("<img alt="" src="/mysite/imagegallery/PublishingImages/Gallery/image.png" style="BORDER&#58;0px solid;" />")`. What's the HTML doing there? You should fix the code that generates this, not work around it.

Comment: I'm not generating the CSS. I'm using a content management system that inserts the CSS. It's referencing the correct image. However, the image doesn't not display because of the text on either side. I need to eliminate the text before and after the image string. @CrazyTrain - Agreed, however this is the output based on the CMS that i'm using. It's essentially <div class="name" style="background-image:ULR(textext"></div> Please let me know if you need more information :)

Comment: so, you are trying to work around a bug that results in invalid CSS rule(s) being emitted?

Comment: Still: Fix the problem by configuring the CMS properly.

Comment: @Tron: So the `src` is unknown, and you need to retrieve it so that you can correctly add the `background-image` style directly to the element?

Comment: I doubt that if fixing the CMS were possible it did not occur to the author :)

Comment: Thanks for all the responses all. @CrazyTrain - The "scr" is defined (as seen in line one of my code above). I just want to know how to extract that line into a variable for example. So i want to remove the  "<img alt" etc, plus everything after ".png" etc.

Comment: @Tron: I understand that it's defined, but your point is that you don't know what it is, so you need to retrieve it, right? If so, the trouble is going to be that the browser is likely going to discard invalid CSS rules, so it won't be available directly from the element.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Thanks for the response. I think i'm finding it difficult to articulate my issue. If we forget the attribute replacement for now. What i'm essentially saying is, say for example i have the following: "<> akjsldk skdjla this is my name kjslkd js <>". I want to strip out everything before and after "this is my name". So, in a varaible i use some form of substring that removes that, and leaves me with the text "this is my name". I want to apply the same notion to the style attribute. Remove everything apart from the image path. I hope that's a tad clearer. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: I agree with @CrazyTrain, you are unlikely to get access to this malformed style. Just give up :) But if you do access it, try searching it for a regular expression like /src="[^"]"/ or something like that and hope that it works.

Comment: @Tron: Yes, there are string manipulation methods in JavaScript. For example, there's `.replace()`, which can use a string or a regular expression to target the removal. But that's not the hard part. The first step is actually obtaining the string that you need to manipulate. That's what I'm trying to focus on. If you just want to know how to do the replace once you have the string, that's pretty easy. If you can get the text of the entire stylesheet in your code, you could actually use `.innerHTML` to make pretty easy work of it.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - I can get the string through a $(this).attr('style') - Which returns everything. I just need to reduce it to the image path :) Thanks for your time, massively appreciated

Comment: @Tron: Oh, this in an inline style? I thought it was part of a style sheet. Well that's easy. Seems like you have an answer below that should do it, though there are several approaches. Since you seem to have jQuery, you could do `$($(this).attr("style")).filter("img").prop("src")`;

Comment: @CrazyTrain: You assume that `$(this).attr("style")` returns a valid HTML string. The example in the question is not though.

Comment: @FelixKling: I forgot that it had extra stuff. Simple fix though. `$("<p>"+$(this).attr("style")+"</p>").find("img").prop("src");`

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Indeed that could actually work :D Still, horrible workaround.

Comment: @FelixKling I believe that html is well formed, but image url is invalid. So, the solution will work for Tron.

Comment: @FelixKling: Actually I'd feel safer having the DOM doing the parsing, and extracting the resulting image... since we're dealing with HTML. A regex solution would seem a little fragile to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix the problem at your CMS. But to answer your question, you could do this.

HTML

```
<div id="screwedByCMS" style='background-image: url("<img alt="" src="/mysite/imagegallery/PublishingImages/Gallery/image.png" style="BORDER&#58;0px solid;" />"); background-attachment: scroll; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-color: transparent;'></div>
```

Javascript

```
var screwedByCMS = document.getElementById("screwedByCMS"),
    imageURL = screwedByCMS.attributes.style.nodeValue.match(/src="(\S+?)"/);

console.log(imageURL[1]);
```

Returns

```
/mysite/imagegallery/PublishingImages/Gallery/image.png
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Dvgch/)

Answer (score -2):

You could use regex

```
var matches = '<img alt="" src="..."'.match(new RegExp("src=\"([a-zA-Z0-9/.]+)\""));
var srcString = matches[1];
```

Comment: I was unsure of the user's requirements for the file naming, updated to accept numbers, alternatively if you'd like to be really flexible "src=\"[^\"]+\""

Comment: I understand, however I think it wise to assume that the image name can use any characters (except whitespace), for example `image_3.png`

Comment: Good point! I'll keep that in mind when answering in the future.